# Aggregate and count repeating messages with flux

Tags: influxdb, flux

I have a table from a log file where the values represent the log message as a string. Messages repeat often, so using the query:

```
from(bucket: "my_bucket")
  |> range(start: v.timeRangeStart, stop: v.timeRangeStop)
```

returns something like the following:

| Time | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Message 1 |
| 2 | Message 1 |
| 3 | Message 2 |
| 4 | Message 2 |
| 5 | Message 2 |
| 6 | Message 1 |

And i want it to look something like this:

| Time | Value | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Message 1 | 2 |
| 3 | Message 2 | 3 |
| 6 | Message 1 | 1 |

Any ideas how to write the flux query?

I don't know where to start...